# LVM issues and questions

Tags: rhel, lvm

I've got a NAS configured with LVM where one of the volumes is giving errors like this:

```
  vgscan 
  reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  /dev/ElkhornC7VG1/idisk5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 1610612670464: Input/output error
  /dev/ElkhornC7VG1/idisk5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 1610612727808: Input/output error
  /dev/ElkhornC7VG1/idisk5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/ElkhornC7VG1/idisk5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
```

The volume itself is in a "read-only filesystem" state in which no files are available. An fsck revealed some issues with damaged data blocks, which leads me to believe it is unrecoverable.

There are archives of this volume under /etc/lvm/archive, but I'm relatively new to working with LVM and don't know how to successfully restore this snapshot. Has anyone dealt with something like this before? Can you share your knowledge and shine some light on the situation?